# Handle click on arbitrary Swing component

Tags: java, swing, click

Is there any way to respond to a click on a Swing component that isn't a JButton or similar? JLabels, JTextAreas, etc. don't have addActionListener(...) methods; is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a mouse listener. See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `MouseListener`.  Every `Component` has [`addMouseListener(MouseListener)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29).

Comment: Yours had one more link.  It was worth the wait.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [MouseListerner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) instead

Look for [Component.addMouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener%28java.awt.event.MouseListener%29)